# Combine 3 grayscale images to 1 natural color image in Python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors

I am dealing with a dataset on Kaggle.com:
https://www.kaggle.com/sorour/38cloud-cloud-segmentation-in-satellite-images
And what I'm trying to do is combine 3 grayscale image represent 3 channels (R, G, B) to one natural color image. So here is what I've tried:

```
r_np = np.array(cv2.imread(red, 0))
g_np = np.array(cv2.imread(green, 0))
b_np = np.array(cv2.imread(blue, 0))

# Add the channels to the final image
final_img = np.dstack([b_np, g_np, r_np]).astype(np.uint8)

# Directory to save
final_img_dir = store_directory + "\\" + "img" + image_id

# Save the needed multi channel image
cv2.imwrite(final_img_dir, final_img)
```

And its output is a still a grayscale image. My image format is .TIF.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Your code worked as expected on my PC. The problem seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Ah, I think I know why. Can you please check if those `red`, `green`, `blue` are not the same image? If they are, the RGB values of the output will be the same, which means you will have a 3-channel grayscale image.

Comment: I'm so sorry for posting this question as my code work just right, it's just the color of the final image is only white and gray as it is a picture of a mountian top! So sorry for bother everyone.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have several problems in your code:

Firstly, you need to import modules:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
```

Secondly, you are using ugly, manifest constants instead of the nice, legible, maintainable ones that OpenCV provides for free and also you are needlessly wrapping the Numpy array you get from `cv2.imread()` into a Numpy array.

Finally, you are not checking for errors.

So, rather than:

```
r_np = np.array(cv2.imread(red, 0))
```

consider:

```
r_np = cv2.imread(filename, cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
assert r_np is not None, "ERROR: Error reading red image"
```

Comment: Thank you a thousand times. By the way, this is just a part of my code and I've imported everything. Anyway, thank you.